# Getting existing paypal account and email account error

Tags: php, paypal

I have used the paypal express checkout payment method with config value 'SOLUTIONTYPE=sole' which enable the user to make the payment with debit or credit card but when I am trying to make the payment after filling the all the testing card details I get the below error:

"You cannot use an email address or card number that belongs to an existing PayPal account. If you have a PayPal account, please log in. If you don't, please change the email address or card number and try again."

Is there any option that I disable to checked the existing account..

See the below configuration value
$padata = '&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout';

```
    $padata .= '&RETURNURL=' . urlencode(PPL_RETURN_URL);
    $padata .= '&CANCELURL=' . urlencode(PPL_CANCEL_URL);
    $padata .= '&SOLUTIONTYPE=' . urlencode('sole');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means the email address that you filled in the credit card payment option has been linked to a registered paypal account. So please update to a  new email address or that is never linked to an existing paypal account will bypass this error immediately.